# Stochastic process similar to poisson-process but where I can tune mu and sigma independently?

Tags: poisson-process, pymc, stan

I've tried to find an answer to my question via Google, but without luck. Therefore I ask now here:
Is there a stochastic process similar to the poisson-process, but for which I can tune mu and sigma independently? The poisson-process let's me tune only the lambda parameter, which then determins mu and sigma.

Ideally you could also point me to a pymc3 or stan example that shows how to fit such a process to data.

Thanks,
Christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer to my question. A friend pointed me towards the paper:
[Some Generalizations of Poisson Processes](http://www.mscs.mu.edu/~jsta/issues/11(3)/JSTA11(3)p2.pdf). On first sight the "Gamma Count Model" of chapter 2 looks most like what I was looking for.

I still have to see how to integrate that into an MCMC software like PyMC3 or Stan. But that's a different matter.

Answer (score 0):

The Poisson process can be understood as an approximation of the Binomial(n,p), where:

lambda = n * p as n goes to infinity.

The expectation of the Binomial is n * p, and its variance n * p * (1-p), so given expectation and variance you can determine n and p. Of course, how much this process is like the Poisson process depends on how large n is.